# Spring Webflux how to keep subsciption alive after reciving last element from repository

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I want to create an endpoint that will be streaming data to the client (React app) until the client won't say 'ok, I'm done'. The data is a list of user events that are fetched from mongo.
Get endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(produces = [MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE])
fun streamEvents(@RequestParam userId: String): Flux<UserEvent> {
    return userEventRepository.findAllByUserId(userId)
}
```

Current implementation closes subscription when receiving the last element. I don't want to keep that connection alive for a long time. I guess it will be 30sec up to 1min. When the connection is active client will be creating new events using POST endpoint.

```
@PostMapping
fun createUserEvent(@RequestBody userEventRequest: UserEventRequest): Mono<UserEvent> {
    return userEventRepository.save(UserEvent(userEventRequest.userId))
}
```

This is just an example to make it simpler. Instead of calling save on repo I want to make it async so there will be an event fired, handler will do some calculations and save UserEvent to the database. And now I want display that created event on the client side. Can I achieve that using event stream or maybe I need use something different like websockets? The perfect solution will be something like this

```
@GetMapping(produces = [MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE])
fun streamEvents(@RequestParam userId: String): Flux<UserEvent> {
    return userEventRepository.findAllByUserId(userId).takeUntil { it.status != "FINISHED" }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have previously used `ServerSentEvents`for this type of logic and keeping the connection alive by sending `keep alive` messages during a given interval.

Here is a code example from one of my previous projects, where i merge in the `keep alive` messages alongside the regular events.

```
.GET("", accept(TEXT_EVENT_STREAM), request -> ok()
        .contentType(TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
        .header("Cache-Control", "no-transform")
        .body(Flux.merge(myHandler.getEvents()), 
                  Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(15))
                          .map(aLong -> ServerSentEvent.builder()
                                                       .comment("keep alive")
                                                       .build())),
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyEvents>>() {}))
```